# Нужно вывести информацию о компании, например - на каком этаже здания находится компания. Использовать функцию findOrganization ()

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Пытался по-разному написать код для вывода информации из Яндекс. Карта, но как не писал, результата не было. Нужно использовать функцию findOrganization ()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Карта Яндекс</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=api&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
        #info {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <script>
        const apiKey = ""; 
        const organizationId = "1186386819"; // ID организации

        ymaps.ready(function() {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: [55, 38], // центр карты (Москва)
                zoom: 14 // масштаб карты
            });

            ymaps.geocode('Москва', { results: 1 }).then(function(res) {
                // Получаем первый результат геокодирования
                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

                // Задаем геобъекту свойства и опции
                firstGeoObject.properties.set({
                    iconContent: 'Москва',
                    balloonContent: 'Столица России'
                });

                // Добавляем геообъект на карту
                myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);
            });

            ymaps.findOrganization(organizationId).then(
                function (orgGeoObject) {
                    console.log(orgGeoObject);
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(orgGeoObject);
                    myMap.setBounds(orgGeoObject.geometry.getBounds());
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );

            ymaps.vow
                .require([
                    "search",
                    "geocode"
                ])
                .spread(function (search, geocode) {
                    search(apiKey, `ID ${organizationId}`, {
                        type: "biz"
                    })
                    .then(function (res) {
                        const features = res.features;

                        if (features.length) {
                            const object = features[0];
                            const id = object.properties.id;
                            const name = object.properties.name;
                            const address = object.properties.address;
                            const phone = object.properties.CompanyMetaData.Phones[0].formatted;
                            const floors = object.properties.floors;

                            // вывод информации об организации на страницу
                            const infoElement = document.getElementById("info");
                            infoElement.innerHTML = `
                                <p>Название: ${name}</p>
                                <p>ID Организации: ${id}</p>
                                <p>Адрес: ${address}</p>
                                <p>Телефон: ${phone}</p>
                                <p>Этаж: ${floors}</p>
                            `;
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                });
       

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция [**findOrganization()**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization.html) предназначена для добавления геообъекта организации на карту, а не выгрузку данных в пользовательские базы (что, к слову, запрещают [условия использования API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/)). И потому её ответ (состав объекта) недокументирован – он предназначен лишь для отрисовки корректного балуна в том виде, который задумал Яндекс.

Пример кода, способный отобразить найденный объект и послать его в консоль:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init(ymaps) {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55, 38],
        zoom: 14
    });

    ymaps.findOrganization('1124715036').then(
        function (orgGeoObject) {
        console.log(orgGeoObject);
        myMap.geoObjects.add(orgGeoObject);
        orgGeoObject.balloon.open();
    },
        function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: У меня по-прежнему не выводит.. Если Вас не затруднит, то может показать конкретно вместо чего нужно вставить Ваш блок кода?

Comment: Это весь js-код для вывода данных в консоль. И он точно рабочий. Остальное - html-обёртка. Соберите свой пример на jsbin.com , чтобы можно было разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Заменил, информацию теперь выводит, но на карте, а не внизу

Comment: Так метод findOrganization для этого и предназначен. В orgGeoObject есть некоторые из нужных вам поля - поковыряйтесь в структуре ответа, который в консоль [F12] отправлен. Но поскольку структура недокументирована, она может меняться и ломать работу вашего кода, если вы будете основываться на текущей форме ответа.

Comment: Как я не пытался, ничего не получилось

Comment: Да что именно-то не получилось? Покажите наработки в jsbin.com хотя бы – подскажем, куда копать. Время работы в блок 'time' из того же кода выводится строкой: `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = 'Время работы: ' + orgGeoObject.properties.get('workingTime');`

Comment: Обновил в первом сообщении код, т.к. сюда он полностью не помещается. Выводит карту, но информация должна быть под картой, а не на ней

Comment: Добавьте в вызов API ваш ключ, а нужные поля, которые есть в объекте ответа добавляйте по мере необходимости. https://jsbin.com/jiduvaq/edit?html,output

Comment: Этаж не выводит, добавил 2 строчки (в нужные места):
const floors = object.properties.get('floors')
и 
<p>Этаж: ${floors}</p>
Вместо вывода пишет: "Этаж: undefined"

Comment: А где вы в объекте ответа этаж увидели? Вам же специально объект в консоль вывели - console.log(orgGeoObject). Раскройте объект "c" (перед адресом) в консоли и там в properties→_data найдёте все доступные для обработки данные. Этажей "floors" там нет, тогда зачем их пытаться искать? Изучите объект ответа внимательней, пожалуйста!

Comment: Так и не понял, как этаж вывести

Comment: Никак вы этаж не выведете! Нет этой информации в Яндексе.

Comment: Ну а статус организации (например, временно не работает) вывести можно?

Comment: Не надо спрашивать то, что можно посмотреть самостоятельно. Раскройте и посмотрите поля объекта в консоли из вышеупомянутого примера. Что там есть, то и сможете выловить. https://radikal.host/i/XMi1Ba

Comment: Хорошо, у меня выводит график работы, а нельзя как-то сделать чтобы выводился статус в конкретно данный момент времени? ("Работает",  "Не работает")

Comment: Насколько вижу, в ответе эта информация возвращается в поле workingStatus.isWork. true - значит работает, а в workingStatus.time прописано время, до которого часа