# Можно ли использовать searchcontrol внутри нарисованного круга в yandexmaps или только в прямоугольник?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

И можно ли узнать данные о метке searchcontrol и вывести их, данные о названии места, время его работы и адрес

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про ограничение зоны поиска через [boundedBy](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl.html), то ограничить поиск можно только прямоугольной зоной произвольные полигоны или круг выбрать для этого нельзя. Вы можете только фильтровать результаты поиска через [searchInside(circle)](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult.html#method_detail__searchInside), как это показано в [примере Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle).

Вывод результата поиска в консоль, например - это уже следующая задача, суть которой - обработка результата и выбор из ответа нужных вам полей. Пример подобного вопроса тут был не так давно - [Нужно вывести информацию о компании, например - на каком этаже здания находится компания. Использовать функцию findOrganization ()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1506995/386299)
Ознакомьтесь и попробуйте собрать свой минимальный рабочий пример – сможете приложить его сюда, если с деталями потребуется помощь.